# How to change the name of the document=True field of Haystack in Django?

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I want to use haystack, but all my models have "body" as their text-field name. it is the same on all models though.

Now I get this error:

```
All 'SearchIndex' classes must use the same 'text' fieldname for the 'document=True' field. Offending index is '<qna.search_indexes.QuestionIndex object at 0x2435328>'.
```

That's the index file:

import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from qna.models import Question

```
class QuestionIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    subject = indexes.CharField(document=False, use_template=False)
    body = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True, model_attr='user')
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

    def get_model(self):
        return Question

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

It is the ONLY one! With what is it offending? As far as I understand the field name doesn't have to be "text" it only has to be the same on every field. But it's the only field! Do I have to change some config? What might be the cause of this... ??

Answer (score 1):

I saw your error in the haystack source. It looks like there is a setting for the name of this field (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/utils/loading.py#L154):

```
self.document_field = getattr(settings, 'HAYSTACK_DOCUMENT_FIELD', 'text')
```

Later in that file (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/utils/loading.py#L222) it checks to make sure that your index name matches and blows up with the error you saw if they don't agree:

```
if field_object.index_fieldname != self.document_field:
    raise SearchFieldError("All 'SearchIndex' classes must use the same '%s' fieldname for the 'document=True' field. Offending index is '%s'." % (self.document_field, index))
```

If you set HAYSTACK_DOCUMENT_FIELD to "body" in your settings, it looks like that should do it.